# Date en javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Como puedo determinar un dia en concreto y saber cuantos habra de aqui a una determinada fecha, por ejemplo: Si quiero saber cuantas veces caera San Juan en sabado de aqui al 2100. Me imagino que deberia de hacer varias condiciones pero no se como exponerlo en codigo alguien podria ayudar?

Saludos.

Comment: Comienza por poner aquí lo que has hecho y cuales son tus dudas concretas. Tu pregunta es básicamente que te expliquemos todo. Traslada a código todas esas condiciones que comentas.

Comment: Divide tu problema en partes más pequeñas y manejables, atiende cada una de ellas y realiza preguntas concretas y específicas. De ser posible incluye un __[mcve]__ que lo ilustre.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No tienes más que ir creando los objetos `Date` correspondientes a cada año de aquí al 2100 y comprobar el día de la semana con el método `getDay`:

```js
var cont = 0;
for(var year=(new Date()).getFullYear()+1; year<=2100; year++){
  var sanJuan = new Date(year, 5, 23);
  if (sanJuan.getDay()===6){
    console.log('El ' + sanJuan.toLocaleDateString() + ' caerá en sábado.');
    cont++;
  }
}

console.log('De aquí al 2100 San Juan caerá en sábado ' + cont + ' veces.');
```

Comment: Gracias Asier por tu respueta. Aunque seria mejor que esperaras a que el autor añadiera más informacion de lo que trató de hacer para no *estar resolviendole un programa que de momento parece que no ha intentado* . Un saludo

Comment: Cierto. Tienes toda la razón. Ok.